# Lead Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

I have a Validation Rule for Leads and it's working perfectly fine, but I now want to make the State required, where applicable.

I have created the below, but it doesn't execute, unfortunately.

My Validation Rule is:

```
AND(

IsConverted = TRUE,
ISBLANK(State),
CASE(Country,
"United Arab Emirates",1,
"Australia",1,
"Brazil",1,
"Canada",1,
"Switzerland",1,
"China",1,
"Germany",1,
"Spain",1,
"United Kingdom",1,
"Ireland",1,
"India",1,
"Italy",1,
"Mexico",1,
"Netherlands",1,
"Sweden",1,
"Thailand",1,
"United States of America",1,

0)=1,

OR(

ISBLANK (field1),
ISBLANK (field2),
ISBLANK (TEXT(field3)),
ISBLANK (TEXT(field4)),
ISBLANK(Country),
ISBLANK(Street),
ISBLANK(City),
ISBLANK(PostalCode),
ISBLANK(State)

)
)
```

Thanks a lot.

**Initial Validation:** - that works:

```
AND(

IsConverted = TRUE

&& 

OR(

ISBLANK (field1),
ISBLANK (field2),
ISBLANK (TEXT(field3)),
ISBLANK (TEXT(field4)),
ISBLANK(Country),
ISBLANK(Street),
ISBLANK(City),
ISBLANK(PostalCode),
ISBLANK(State)

)
```

Comment: What exactly is the scenario you expect it to execute, but it didn't.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - Hi Kris, Thanks for coming back to me. I want the users not to be allowed to convert the Lead, until all the above is required. For some of the countries, there is no state, so I don't want the validation to execute.

Comment: Double check your country values. For example, I believe it should be `United States` vs. `United States of America`.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - Just double-checked the values and they are all correct. Any other ideas what I am missing?

Comment: I would simplify it and remove the `Case` function out of it to debug. Simply put `Country = "Mexico"` and see if it works on a lead with a country of Mexico. The last thing is to check what happens to the converted lead, does it have a state after being converted from some other process (ex. trigger).

Comment: Thanks. I think my logic isn't quite right since I have added "AND( + CASE" function. If I remove AND & CASE and only leave "IsConverted = TRUE, && OR( function", it works, but it won't make my state required, before conversion. Let me try with Country = "Mexico"  :)

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - Hi Kris, I have just tried with Country = Mexico, but it let me convert the lead. The logic isn't correct.

Comment: And what are the values in the converted lead/contact? Does it have a state value? Do you have any other automation/code that runs on conversion?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - Hi Kris, I have amended my post with the initial validation that works. I want the users to fill in all the info before conversion and it works perfectly fine. I want to add a condition that if the country has a state, the state should be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add a condition that if the country has a state, the state should be required.
>
> I have just tried with Country = Mexico, but it let me convert the lead. The logic isn't correct

So, I've tested this, and currently if you put country = mexico in your lead, validation works - if you have country=mexico and state field blank (or any of the other fields - field1 etc.) it prevents conversion.

However, if you have a country not from that list, there is no validation - it lets everything through.

Given your comment, I would recommend amending the validation rule to:

```
AND(
IsConverted=TRUE,

OR(
ISBLANK(Country),
ISBLANK(Street),
ISBLANK(City),
ISBLANK(PostalCode),
AND(ISBLANK(State),
CASE(Country,
"United Arab Emirates",1,
"Australia",1,
"Brazil",1,
"Canada",1,
"Switzerland",1,
"China",1,
"Germany",1,
"Spain",1,
"United Kingdom",1,
"Ireland",1,
"India",1,
"Italy",1,
"Mexico",1,
"Netherlands",1,
"Sweden",1,
"Thailand",1,
"United States of America",1,

0)=1)
))
```

This would check validation of most fields for all countries, but only check  the state field for the countries in your CASE function.

I don't know why the validation for Mexico isn't working in your org, since copy pasting your code as is, it did work in my sandbox - so perhaps there are some other issues going on there - maybe see if there is anything else changing the values.

One final point - the United Kingdom doesn't have states!

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for coming back to me. Very odd, indeed, but it didn't prevent the conversion for Country = Mexico. However, I have now amended my Validation, as per above and it works, so thanks a lot for your help :). I only want the Validation to check for the countries in the CASE function. So better say State/Province.  Thanks a lot once again.